# Sass - variable with @include as value

Tags: sass

I created a simple mixin that makes a gradient with the colors fed into the mixin:

```
@mixin bgGradient($color1, $color2) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, $color1 0%, $color2 100%);
}
```

I am trying to store that mixin call in a variable:

```
$foo: @include bgGradient(#fff, #000);
```

However, I get an error when trying to do that:

```
Invalid CSS after "...foo:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@include bgGrad...")
```

Is it possible to store a mixin call in a variable? If so, how does one obtain this power? I have scoured the Internet and cannot seem to find this problem being mentioned...

Comment: What are you expecting the variable to contain?

Comment: Are you trying to use the variable as part of other css selectors? If so you should use the `@extend` directive. More info [here](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7).

Comment: No, using `@extend` is not what I am attempting to do because I cannot change the arguments/parameters of the mixin if it is called from a class that I am extending. I am expecting for the `$foo` variable to print out `background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #000 100%);`, where `#fff` and `#000` can be changed to different colors.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `@extend` directive.

```
@mixin bgGradient($color1, $color2) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, $color1 0%, $color2 100%);
}

%foo{
  @include bgGradient(#fff, #000);
}

//Example code
.my-div{
  @extend %foo;
}
```